# Cannot display pdf using abobe pdf reader in android

Tags: android, pdf

Iam using a method to open pdf file stored in my sd card in android app using adobe pdf reader. Code that I am using is given below.

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+"/Report.pdf");
            Uri path=Uri.fromFile(file);
            //openFile(file, "application/pdf");
            viewPdf(path);


private void viewPdf(Uri file){
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
    try{
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
    builder.setMessage("Download from Android Market?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
    startActivity(marketIntent);

    }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
    builder.create().show();

    }
}
```

And the following exception is diplayed in toast: Cannot display pdf(xyz.pdf cannot be opened).

Please help me out guys.

Comment: is there any pdf reader app in installed on your device or emulator ?

Comment: Try to set package in intent like :  intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");

Comment: @HareshChhelana yes there are two installed one is adobe other is polaris office 5... and yes I used the com.adobe.reader still the same exception. If you have a working example please do post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try open specific pdf reader app using identify by package name :

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: no help still the same problem " cannot open Report.pdf " anyways the size of pdf is 323 kb does it matter??

Comment: have you try to open some other pdf file ?